# Running an IF statement for all worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

I have data arranged in Excel like so:

```
Year|Trade Flow|Commodity Code|Commodity|Qty Unit|Qty|Net Weight|Trade Value
```

I have an IF formula:

```
=IF(D2=D1,0,IF(D3=D2,ABS(I3-I2),I2))
```

which I need to run for all the worksheets in the file, using VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you know how to find the last cell (plenty of examples on this site), or have a fixed size.

I used column H just for an example.

```
for each sh in sheets
    sh.range("H2:H20").Formula="=IF(D2=D1,0,IF(D3=D2,ABS(I3-I2),I2))"
next
```

alter this to suit your needs